# css table width not working properly

Tags: html, css, oracle, html-table

I have trouble with css when i use `<style>` element in oracle function. I have created simple example. Body has fixed width. Table has width set to 100%. When i use `<style>` element it does not work properly. When i use link to css file instead of `<style>` element it works fine. But in oracle function i need to use `<style>` element to format table not link.

Here is example using `<style>` element: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2q0qoh8f/)

And example without `<style>` element: [link1](https://jsfiddle.net/uyfgx82o/)

Comment: The first example of using the `<style>` element is wrong because the CSS part in jsfiddle should contain **only** css. and not the `<style>` tag

Comment: why do u even have a fixed body? try and have a div inside a body that are fixed instead.

Comment: okey but the same problem i have in oracle function. Text formating and other works fine. There is only problem with width parameter.

Comment: @Alen.Toma with div fixed width it work properly. Thank you

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: @Alen.Toma it still not working in oracle function. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with where you are placing the `<style>` tags.

Based on your first example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/koqo3x7o/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<style type="text/css">
body {

  width:300px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
table,th,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

alright this is an example

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      width:300px;
    }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
    table,th,td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: separate;
        width:100% !important;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: it still not working. I can change other parameters (font size, color, border ... in div) but i am not able to change width of div in Oracle function.

Comment: try to add !important; and see what happen, it would also be nice if u publish your demo so i could Inspect your setting with chrome.